# Trying to make a basic JS game, hiding table row isn't working for me

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make it so that when you click the "shrine" button, it dissappears the row and appears the 'temple' row.

http://pastebin.com/Xugp5twQ

html/js/css separated by multiple line breaks.

Comment: Hi, first of all put this line <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script> just before closing the body tag

Comment: Thanks, I read a guide that said at the beginning, but I trust people here more than most of the internet.

Answer (score 1):

`display: ''` is a void CSS property for *#temple*.
Hence, you need to assign `document.getElementById('temple').style.display`  as `table-row`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it seems to still not work. Neither the Shrine row disappears or the Temple row appears

Comment: Nevermind, I'm just an idiot, accidentally capitallized getElementByID

Comment: Yes, I had noticed that in your pastebin code, and changed it while looking through it. Forgot to update you about it.

Answer (score 0):

The `display` property of your CSS rule was not overridden properly.

Just replace

```
document.getElementById('temple').style.display = '';
```

with

```
document.getElementById('temple').style.display = 'table-row';
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it seems to still not work. Neither the Shrine row disappears or the Temple row appears.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm just an idiot, accidentally capitallized getElementBy**ID**